# tensorflow with custom training loop and tf.data.dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to build a Tensorflow model with custom training loop to use the forecast to feed the inputs of the next time step. The model has two heads and inputs set. I got problem to find how to pass my two inputs and manage how to deal with the custom call function.

I use this ref to build my code:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#advanced_autoregressive_model

and here an example of my data and the way I want to use it for each timestep iteration.

Input #1:

```
|---input warm up/observed data---|--- forcast---------------------|
          t-5    t-4    t-3    t-2    t-1    t-0     t+1    t+2    t+3   
  var#1    3       2      1      5      4      2       1      3     4   
  var#2    1      -1     -3      1      0     -5      -11     0     1    
  var#3    66     67     69     71      73    75       ?      ?     ?
```

Using this example, var1-2 are inputs, var3 inputs AND labels. Var3 is known on first times steps with a lag on 1 day (today we know last day value of var3) to start model.

First iteration I get these inputs and try to forecast a value that will be inserted in var3 t+1 fore the next iteration:

```
          t-5    t-4    t-3    t-2    t-1    t-0     t+1 
  var#1    3       2      1      5      4      2          
  var#2    1      -1     -3      1      0     -5          
  var#3    66     67     69     71      73    75       ?
```

If ? =88 the next inputs for next iteration will look like this:

```
          t-5    t-4    t-3    t-2    t-1    t-0     t+1    t+2  
  var#1    3       2      1      5      4      2       1            
  var#2    1      -1     -3      1      0     -5      -11            
  var#3    66     67     69     71      73    75     ?=88     ?
```

Input #2 is just a sequence of 3 values for the second head of model using only dense layer.

```
class FeedBack(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, num_timesteps_in, num_timesteps_out, nb_features, nb_attributs,
                 nb_lstm_units, nb_dense_units):
        super(FeedBack, self).__init__()
        self.num_timesteps_in = num_timesteps_in
        self.num_timesteps_out = num_timesteps_out
        self.nb_features = nb_features
        self.nb_attributs = nb_attributs
        self.nb_lstm_units = nb_lstm_units
        self.nb_dense_units = nb_dense_units

        self.lstm_cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(nb_lstm_units)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_lstm_units)


    def call(self, inputs, training=None):

        predictions = []
        inputs1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(self.num_timesteps_in + self.num_timesteps_out, self.nb_features))
        inputs2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(self.nb_attributs))

        # Run prediction steps by step with a rolling window on the inputs
        for i in range(0, self.num_timesteps_out):
        
            input_chunk = inputs1[i:i + self.num_timesteps_in, :]

            # Execute one step.
            extraction_info = self.lstm_cell(self.nb_lstm_units, 
                                             training=training,
                                             return_sequences=False, 
                                             stateful=False)(input_chunk)

            extraction_info = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(extraction_info)

        
        # -------------- Merge les inputs météo/apports avec les attributs physiographiques --------------------

            merged_input = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1, name='merged_head')([extraction_info, inputs2])

            merged_input = self.Dense(self.nb_dense_units)(merged_input)

            merged_input = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(merged_input)

            prediction = self.Dense(1, activation='linear')(merged_input)

            # insert this forecast into the input1 on the next timestep
            inputs1[i + self.num_timesteps_in + 1, -1] = prediction
            # Add the prediction to the record for extracting at the end.
            predictions.append(prediction)

        return predictions
```

Now format to tf. dataset an train model

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rates[1])

# inputs convertion to tf.data.dataset
inputs_hydro = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X1))
inputs_static = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X2))
output = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((y))
combined_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(((inputs_hydro, inputs_static), output))
input_dataset = combined_dataset.batch(5)

base_model = cr.FeedBack(10, 5, 2, 3, 50, 50)
base_model.call = cr.call
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
history = model.fit(input_dataset,
                    verbose=0,
                    epochs=10)
```

At this point, I tried a lot of things and read many examples and questions but still am unable to make it run. The actual version I got this error:

> File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2.7_bigData\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\rnn\lstm.py", line 190, in build
> input_dim = input_shape[-1]
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range
>
> Call arguments received by layer "feed_back" "                 f"(type FeedBack):
> • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 15, 3), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 24), dtype=float32)')
> • training=True

Any help will be really welcome! It is my first use of `tf.data.dataset` and of custom layer/model, it is a hard step in my learning.

Comment: `def call(self, inputs, training=None):` is not properly indented

Comment: thank!, I did the correction, code above corrected with the new error code, still not working